# Why is position fixed not working?

Tags: html, css

I am just trying to stick header to the top. I have set `position` to `fixed` and `top:0px;` and `left:0px`.

I have uploaded [my code here](http://bintars.net/mobile/test/index.html).

Below is the CSS class for header:

```
header.header
{ 
    background: #861912;
    padding:5px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 43px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Please help me finding out what stopping my header to stick at top.

Comment: The CSS that you claim to have isn't there. That's the problem.

Comment: @BoltClock just hold on for a sec. I have uploaded incorrect code by mistake.

Comment: Indeed, and when i add them myself it is fixed to the top of the browser though..

Comment: @Bokdem Please check now.

Comment: @BoltClock please check now.

Comment: In Chrome it is at the top, what browser are you using?

Comment: Also, in my firefox it is at the top. We're talking about the red bar containing 'Home', right?

Comment: Yes @Bokdem. I have tried it in my Chrome as well. It is not sticking at top. I am on Mac it it could be reason.

Comment: @Bokdem and I also tried it in Chrome on Windows 8 of one of my colleague. Its not stick.

Comment: If you want the navbar fixed then why don't you put it out of other divs and directly inside body, this way it will work fine.

Comment: @MinderSaini I have placed `header` directly in body. But it makes header hidden. Now cannot find why it is hidden. I have updated code on server.

Comment: Thanx @MinderSaini. Adding `z-index` worked. You are great. If you could write an answer than I will select your answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the Navbar out of other divs and directly inside body and increase it's z-index, this way it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be this line:

```
.container {
    ...
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

(and, of cource, the variant without prefix too).

If I remove it via Developer Tools, everything works fine.

But I'd rather move that `<header>` completely outside the container.

Comment: Removing transform properties will remove animations. I have placed `header` directly in body. But it makes header hidden. Now cannot find why it is hidden. I have updated code on server.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occur by `transform` css property. try it after remove `transform` from `.container`